# HTML5 audio pauses when another is clicked -- IE issues

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have an HTML page that holds a few HTML5 audio embeds. It's setup so that when one is playing and another is clicked, it pauses the first. Therefore, there should be no two audio files playing simultaneously. I've got it working in Firefox and Chrome, but no luck in IE.

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dledet1/55vag/11/

Also, here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!-- AUDIO 1 -->
<p><a onClick="EvalSound('song1'); return true;" target="player"><IMG SRC="http://designlab360.org/fhi/splash/dev2/images/arrow-right.png" BORDER=0 WIDTH=30 HEIGHT=29></a>    
<audio id="song1" src="http://designlab360.org/fhi/splash/dev2/audio/wash-song1_2.mp3" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>

<!-- AUDIO 2 -->
<p><a onClick="EvalSound('song2'); return true;" target="player"><IMG SRC="http://designlab360.org/fhi/splash/dev2/images/arrow-right.png" BORDER=0 WIDTH=30 HEIGHT=29></a>   
<audio id="song2" src="http://designlab360.org/fhi/splash/dev2/audio/wash-song2_2.mp3" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio></p>
```

Javascript:

```
var currentPlayer;
function EvalSound(soundobj) {

 var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
 if(currentPlayer  && currentPlayer != thissound) {
      currentPlayer.pause(); 
 }
 if (thissound.paused)
            thissound.play();
    else
        thissound.pause();
        thissound.currentTime = 0;
         currentPlayer = thissound;
}
```

Any help is most appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Which version of IE are you having this problem on? I just check IE10 on Windows 7 and it works for me.

Comment: IE 8 and down are not working for me. And, thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was experimenting and it seems to work perfectly in all IE versions from 9 upwards, but the audio will not even play in IE 8. I did a tiny bit of research though, and it turns out that the `<audio>` tag is not supported in pre-IE 9.

Looks like you're going to have no luck in getting it to work in IE8, the only way is by using an embed tag:
    `<embed src="http://designlab360.org/fhi/splash/dev2/audio/wash-song1_2.mp3"`
    `autostart="false" loop="false"  width="145" height="60" align="center"></embed>`

You will have to edit your javascript to compensate for the changes, but I hope I helped.

Comment: Ahh... that will do it. That does help. Thanks so much!

Comment: So, I'm not having much luck now that I have changed it to an embed code. Would you have any suggestions for how to alter the JS to accommodate the embed tag instead of the audio tag? Again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a library such as http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/ that has already solved many of these cross browser issues and provides a common api

Comment: @JoseM - Thanks for that suggestion. I implemented audiojs, but it seems to be producing new skin behind the one already there. If I remove controls from my audio tag, then my play/pause script breaks. Any thoughts? Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @user2884636 do you have a sample jsfiddle that I can look at?

Comment: @user2884636 I actually meant a sample with the audiojs issue you had -- but it doesn't matter I went ahead and took your example and used a different api, mediaelement.js which exposes more of a javascript api.  The nice thing about mediaelement.js is that it already by default functions just the way you want it.  Look at my sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/callado4/55vag/13/ although I also made the big play buttons work which needed a little bit more code

Comment: @JoseM Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out with this. It is much appreciated. Unfortunately, that solution doesn't seem to work in IE8 or 7 for me :-/ I tried out a customizeable HTML5 audio script derived from mediaelement.js. However, I'm trying to add in the Flash fallback... with no luck though. Here is a link to what I'm working on: http://designlab360.org/fhi/splash/689384/index5.html. Again, any other input you can provide would be amazing. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2884636 did you include all of the css, swf and js files as specified in the [installation instructions?](http://mediaelementjs.com/#installation) I checked and it doesn't seem to be on your server. If you noticed, in my example I just used a CDN to avoid having to even have those resources on my server

Comment: Okay, thank you @JoseM! I'll give those installation instructions a try and will keep you posted. Again, thank you!